# Google Cloud platform and Containers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, containers, google-compute-engine

I had following question regarding the container support on Google Cloud Platform.

Does the Google Compute Platform support:

1) Containers on their server OS?

2) Containers inside their virtual machines?

3) Or both options?

Won't the 2) option offer limited performance benefits as the hypervisor overhead is not really eliminated?

Comment: You can check the following link for more information https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers

Answer (score 1):

Containers are a deployment model that's becoming very popular because you can, in a very agnostic way, bundle together an application with its dependencies (libraries, language runtimes, etc.). Containers are *not an alternative to virtual machines*, they are *an alternative to traditional packaging and deployment scenarios*. If you're thinking of them as lightweight VMs, you're in for a bit of a shock, because the benefits, drawbacks, and management model are completely different from a virtual machine.

Because containers do not run their own kernel, and can trivially gain full access to the host system, you will not find a provider which hosts Docker on bare metal. If you do, you should be very suspicious, because this is a tremendous security risk to everyone using the service.

If you do wish to build your own container management solution that runs on bare metal, you can look into tools like [Kubernetes](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes) and [Mesosphere](https://mesosphere.com/) (both of which work equally well in hosted virtual machine instances).

Answer (score 0):

Containers are now available in the Google Cloud Developers console, but it's still in active development. You can check [this link](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/) for more information.